# Javascript date choose with next and prevous button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a UI as shown below, where when use clicks on next button the text box changes to next date and when clicked on previous, should display previous date.

The complexity is that when user clicks on Weekview button it should show week i.e 6 days from selected date e.g. Tuesday 06 - Monday 12

[image]

Could some one please help me with above, if there are any plugins available to achieve this.

Comment: Have a look at jQueryUI [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see an obvious way of doing what you want using the jQueryUI datepicker (maybe I didn't look hard enough) but it's probably worthwhile, as RichardTowers suggests, exploring that. If jQueryUI is overkill for your purposes, you might find [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) (a lightweight JavaScript date library) useful.

If you want to do it yourself, the following should give you a decent starting point (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6u4F3/) also):

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wenesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

function getDateString(date) {
    return days[date.getDay()]
    + " "
    + date.getDate()
    + " "
    + months[date.getMonth()]
    + " "
    + date.getFullYear();
}   

var dateToday = new Date();   
var today = getDateString(dateToday);
var dateWeek = new Date(dateToday.getFullYear(), dateToday.getMonth(), dateToday.getDate() + 7);
var week = getDateString(dateWeek);

console.log("Today", today);
console.log("Week", today, week);
```